# Working with Old Price & Special Price in Magento 2

Tags: special-price, pricing

Im wanting to replicate this pricing look in Magento 2.

[image: Pricing example]

This is the code I used in our magento 1 to accomplish this.

```
            <?php $special_price = $_product->getSpecialPrice(); $regular_price = $_product->getPrice(); ?>
            <?php $saved_amount = $regular_price - $special_price; $saved_percent = 100 * $saved_amount / $regular_price; ?>
        <span class="yousave">Save: <?php echo '$'.number_format($saved_amount,0).' ('.number_format($saved_percent,0).'%)'; ?></span>
```

I am looking to put the equivalent of this in Magento 2.2.5. Magento 2 is using the code below to get pricing. I have been editing /Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml and noticed that M2 handles it differently and I have had no luck coming up with how to do this.

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
   </span> 
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?> 
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I accomplish this in the final_price.phtml to reflect how I have it in working in Magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

Used this code in Magento 2.3.x that I inserted into final_price.phtml:

```
<?php 
    $oldRenderedPrice = $priceModel->getValue();
    $finalRenderedPrice =  $finalPriceModel->getValue();

    if ($oldRenderedPrice > $finalRenderedPrice){
?>
        <div class="saved-label">
<?php
        $amountSaved = number_format(($oldRenderedPrice - $finalRenderedPrice), 2, '.', '');
        $percentSaved = number_format((100*(($oldRenderedPrice - $finalRenderedPrice)/$oldRenderedPrice)), 0);

        echo "Saves: $" . $amountSaved . " (" . $percentSaved . "% Off)";
?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```